# How to change the way an ExtJS button behaves?

Tags: extjs

I have a problem regarding behaviour of an ExtJS Button. When clicked, it is supposed to call a specific controller. My problem: I need to add a dialog box, asking the user to confirm his action(for example: are you sure you want to print? YES/NO). The first button in my code example is the old one, while the second button is the one I am trying to change. Code in the snippet is currently displaying the dialog box, but it doesn't do anything when YES or NO is clicked.

I am far from being an expert in ExtJS(my understanding of the framework could be wrong), please keep that in mind.

```
this.buttons = [{
            text:'Print',
            action:'print',
            iconCls:'icon-excel',
            href: 'print/someFile.docx'
        },{

            text:'Print',
            handler:function(){

                Ext.MessageBox.confirm({
                    title:"Print",
                    msg:"Are you sure about this?",
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                    action:'print'
                    href: 'print/someFile.docx',
                    icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION

         });
        },              
        }];
```

Comment: Hey can you please create some fiddle for this example ?

Comment: The confirmation should go in the controller. How is it hooking up an action to a controller method?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli thanks for the key piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a callback function like:

```
Ext.MessageBox.confirm({
    title:"Print",
    msg:"Are you sure about this?",
    buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
    action:'print'
    href: 'print/someFile.docx',
    icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
    fn: function(btn) {
       if (btn === 'yes') {
           console.log('Yes pressed');
       } else if (btn === 'no') {
           console.log('No pressed');
       } 
    }    
});
```

Comment: For the record: i found out that technically this is a way of getting the job done. But in my case, there was a specific situation where i had to put this decision making in the controller, as @Evan Trimboli suggested. Thank you all for your help.